# Unable to add remote file node to parent node Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to add File nodes to a gatsby source that doesn't create them automatically ([gatsby-source-tumblr](https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-tumblr) in this case). Every node has an array of images associated that I want to download and later convert using Gatsby-Image.

Here's my code so far:

```js
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  store,
  cache,
  getCache,
  createNodeId,
}) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `TumblrPost`) {
    const pathValue = "/posts/" + node.slug
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `path`,
      value: pathValue,
    })
  }

  if (
    node.internal.type === `TumblrPost` &&
    node.photos &&
    node.photos.length
  ) {
    await node.photos.map(async photo => {
      let fileNode
      try {
        fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
          url: photo.original_size.url,
          parentNodeId: node.id,
          getCache,
          createNode,
          cache,
          createNodeId,
          store,
        })
        // Adds a field `localFile` to the node
        // ___NODE appendix tells Gatsby that this field will link to another node
        if (fileNode) {
          photo.localFile___NODE = fileNode.id
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

As suggested in multiple tutorials I've found, I'm using `createRemoteFileNode` to download the images and add them as file nodes. *This part works*, I can see the images being downloaded, and there's a number of items visible in GraphiQL under the `allImageSharp` category.

However **I can't seem to get the association with the parent node to work**. Doing something like `photo.localFile___NODE = fileNode.id` does not seem to have any effect. Experimenting with adding even one image to the parent node (post) doesn't seem to work: When looking at the post node in the GraphiQL inspector, there is no trace of the File node.

I have the feeling I might be missing something obvious, but I've been fiddling with this for hours now and can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could be that `fileNode` doesn't have an id yet? In this example https://alexluong.com/blog/gatsby-image-sharp-from-url they use `createNodeId` like this `createNodeId: id => \`dog-image-sharp-${id}\`` when using `createRemoteFileNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55780317/847689) that helped me fix it. I think the problem was with how I was handling the async loops. I copied the code in which it sets `product.images` (in that other user's codebase) and adapted it to mine, it worked. I'm guessing the _ await Promise.all_ was the key.

Which is weird to me, because some point I brought in the fantastic [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library (something I'm more familiar with than `await` etc.) to make sure there weren't any issues with the looping, and that didn't work. Ah well, such is life. I'm glad it works now.